# Return node position in list based on value using recursion

Tags: javascript, list, recursion

I was tasked to write some functions for lists in JavaScript for my journey through The Odin Project. My struggle now is returning the position of a node that has the same value from a parameter. The recursion works fine, so does updating the variable count which is aimed to be returned when the node value matches the value of the parameter. The console throws `undefined` and I've tried to store the count in a separate variable but it's not worked. There are some forum answers I checked out to find where I'm making a mistake but my code is very close to the voted answers. Does JavaScript have a specific way to handle recursion I should be aware of?

This is my code:

```js
function valuePosition(node, value, count){
    if(node.next === null && node.value !== value){
      console.log('Not in the list');
      return 0;
    }

    if(node.value !== value){
      console.log('Not yet');
      return valuePosition(node.next,value, count+1);
    }else if(node.value === value){
      console.log('Found!');
      return position;
    }
  }
```

Cheers!

[Update]
Based on my recent back and forth with @ScottSauyet I'd like to complement the description of the issue with more context. So this is the recursive function plus the factory that wraps it.

```js
class Node{
  static count = 0;
  constructor(value){
    ++Node.count;
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
    this.previous = null;
  }
} 

function List(value){
//some other methods here
  function valuePosition(node, value, count){
    if(node.next === null && node.value !== value){
      return 0;
    }

    if(node.value !== value){
      return valuePosition(node.next,value, count+1);
    }else if(node.value === value){
      return count;
    }
  }
  return{
    root: new Node(value),
    //some methods here
    find(value){
      valuePosition(this.root);
    }
  }
}

const list = List(89);
list.appendNode(98);
list.appendNode(9835);
list.appendNode(8245);
list.prependNode(9834);
list.prependNode(2345);
console.log(list.find(8245));
//OUTPUT: Undefined
```

I've found the main issue with not being able to return count. Basically, you can't do that from a factory OR a class (I've already tried that). However if I run the valuePosition function outside the factory as an isolated code snippet it works wonders

Comment: I think it's as simple as the fact that you `return position`, when presumably you want to `return count`.  `position` is undefined.  I would suggest that `position` is the better name for the parameter, though.  Something like `const valuePosition = (node, value, pos) => node .value == value ? pos : node .next == null ? -1 : valuePosition (node .next, value, pos + 1)`.  Note that `-1` is the idiomatic signal in JS for not finding a value.

Comment: Hi @ScottSauyet! Yeah that was I wrong name I thought I'd already edited here in Stackoverflow. Although your comment is quite useful for making my current code better. Thanks for that! What happens now is that the recursive function doesn't work withing a factory or a class but it does when taken out and executed as a code snipet if that makes sense. I'm gonna edit the question again to avoid future confusion for people who want to suggest something.

Comment: Actually I'll leave the original, otherwise this thread of comments would be misleading for other community members.

Comment: The code you show is broken in other ways than the use of `valuePosition`.  It has no implementation of `append`/`prependNode` .  But the critical issue is probably that your `find` function doesn't return anything, just calling `valuePosition` and ignoring its result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ScottSauyet! I should've included those function I'd already implemented in my recent update. I just wanted to avoid noise in the question as much as possible but that was not a good idea, I'll get better at updating what I post. 

Just tested your suggestion and it worked, so I'll be refactoring the code and update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I wrote a similar function that outputs a concatenated string with the values of each node. Again, I couldn't get the final result of the recursion so I found out that my function was inside a factory. By taking out the recursive function of the factory I could get the final result of the recursion, this means that the context surrounding my recursion was actually causing the problem. I'm gonna try to call the function in a different way preserving the factory but I might find myself refactoring my code into a class instead.

[Update]

I just needed to return the valuePosition inside find(). This is the final version of my code.

```js
class Node{
  static count = 0;
  constructor(value){
    ++Node.count;
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
    this.previous = null;
  }
}


function List(value) {
  
  function valuePosition (node, value, position){
    if(node.next === null && node.value !== value){
      return -1;
    }
    if(node.value !== value){
      return valuePosition(node.next,value, position+1);
    }else if(node.value === value){
      return position;
    }
  }

  function checkNextNode(node) {
    if (node.next !== null) {
      return checkNextNode(node.next);
    } else {
      return node;
    }
  }

  function containsValue(node, value){
    if(node.next === null && node.value !==value){
      return false;
    }

    if(node.value !== value){
      containsValue(node.next,value);
    }else if(node.value === value){
      return true;
    }
  }

  function printNodeValue(node){
    if(node.next === null){
      return `(${node.value})`;
    }
    return `(${node.value})->` + printNodeValue(node.next);
  }

  return {
    root: new Node(value),
    appendNode: function (value) {
      let head = checkNextNode(this.root);
      head.next = new Node(value);
      head.next.previous = head;
    },
    prependNode: function (value) {
      const temporal = this.root;
      this.root = new Node(value);
      this.root.next = temporal;
    },
    getHead: function () {
      return checkNextNode(this.root);
    },
    getTail: function () {
      return this.root;
    },
    size: function () {
      return Node.count;
    },
    pop: function() {
      let secondLast = checkNextNode(this.root).previous;
      secondLast.next = null;
    },
    contains: function(value){
      containsValue(this.root, value);
    },
    find: function(value){
     return valuePosition(this.root, value, 0);
    },
    ToString: function(){
      return printNodeValue(this.root);
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: [Update] Changing the factory around this recursive function for a class doesn't have any effect on the final result.

Comment: [Update] I could finally find the bug. Function valuePosition is being used by find function in the return part of the factory. This sort of nesting makes getting the result impossible but the reason behind it is to restrict access of the count and node parameter of the valuePosition. I've already tried to encapsulate valuePosition with `#` inside a test class I created but it's more complicated. Question: I'm also an active C++ learner, Am I confusing my self with the coding style / syntax of these two languages?